# Paging through log of events

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, logs

I'm trying to use log events to show the transactions from newest to oldest. The problem is that line like this

> contractHandle.allEvents({ fromBlock: startingBlock, toBlock: 'latest'
>   })

retrieves events from oldest to newest. I would like to present reports showing newest entries at the top. For small amount of entries this is not a problem, but if you want to allow paging through the results, this presents a problem, because each time you would have to go through all of the events to just show one page of results. Any ideas how to do this better?

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve the historical list of events once, store them in a regular Web 2.0 database, update that database as new event appear, and then accomplish the paging/scrolling task exactly as you would have in Web 2.0 days.